# Crouton chroot concern(s) with security?

Tags: linux, chroot, chromebook

I am using a Samsung Chromebook with the Crouton Linux install of which can be found [here](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).

My question is, does installing software that uses `chroot`, open my Chrome Book to vulnerabilities?

**Usage**: I am a software developer, that wishes to use Linux on the Chrome Book to develop on. I am not a Linux expert by any means. I just want an environment that does not put my work, or my new Chrome Book at risk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chroot` provides a minimal isolation mechanism, but is not really designed for security. Its limitation is coming from the fact that once you get root inside the environment the containment can be broken ([chroot-break](http://www.bpfh.net/simes/computing/chroot-break.html)).

But, if you accept the fact that getting root access from inside the chroot is something *hard*, you can consider that `chroot` is a good enough containment security.

Note that most of the secured containers provide an isolation mechanism that root cannot break.